# Understanding higher order functions in PHP

Tags: php, higher-order-functions

I find this piece of code complicated to understand. I will be grateful if i can understand this with illustrations and details.

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

function get_algorithm($rand_seed_fnc) {
    return (odd_even($rand_seed_fnc())) ?
        function($value) {
           return $value * $value;
        } :
        function($value) use ($rand_seed_fnc) {
            return ($value * $value / $rand_seed_fnc()) + 10;
        };
}

function odd_even($value) {
    return ($value % 2 === 0);
}

$rand_seed_fnc = function() { return rand(); };
$results = array_map(get_algorithm($rand_seed_fnc), $data);

var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of multiple returns, closures, obfuscation, bad formatting, nested functions, unused variables are all present in your example.
From what I've tested it also does not consistently return the same values back ( floats ).

I rewrote it to demonstrate the intent behind the logic and it took a bit to unravel unused $rand_seed_fnc in the get_algorithm call and the terrible function to variable assignment.

```
<?php
    // Data to run functions on.
    $data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    function get_algorithm( $iValue ) 
    {
        // Check if value is odd or even and return a different value.
        // Replaces odd_even function.
        // Uses modulus %
        // $value = 1, returns FALSE;
        // $value = 2, returns TRUE;
        // $value = 3, returns FALSE;
        // $value = 4, returns TRUE;
        if( $iValue % 2 === 0 )
        {
            // Square the value if it's even.
            $iReturn = $iValue * $iValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Square the value and divide by a random number then add 10.
            $iReturn = ( $iValue * $iValue / rand() ) + 10;
        }
        return $iReturn;
    }
    $results = array_map( 'get_algorithm', $data );
    var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats quite helpful

Comment: Great clean-up and good points. This was probably someone's attempt at a php cypher generation routine with the obfuscation used to create a false-sense of security.